# Opentelemetry otelcol-contrib Error in logs

Tags: docker, open-telemetry, rancher, open-telemetry-collector

I am seeing an error in the `opentelemetry-collector-agent` logs for a workload running in a kubernetes cluster on RHEL nodes.
I see the following logged in the workload logs:
`2024-01-08T15:10:52.686Z error docker@v0.86.0/docker.go:187 Could not parse docker container Stats for container id {"kind": "receiver", "name": "docker stats", "data_type": "metrics", "id": "xxx" , "error": "context canceled"}`

`2024-01-08T15:10:52.812Z error docker@v0.86.0/docker.go:187 Could not parse docker containerStats for container id {"kind": "receiver", "name": "docker_stats", "data_type": "metrics", "id": "63e1c35364fexxx", "error": "context canceled"}`

When I query the containerid on the host node I can see it relates to the rancher/hyperkube container:

```
63e1c35364fe rancher/hyperkube:v1.24.13-rancher2 "/opt/rke-tools/entr…" 4 months ago Up 7 days kubelet
```

The workload is being used to scrape the /var/run/docker.stats unix socket file and collect metrics from docker.
The error does not appear to adversely affect the workload but I want to be 100% sure.
Does anyone know what may be causing this and how to resolve/remove it?